# Upper bound of Frobenius norm of product of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove that $||AB||_F\leq||A||_2||B||_F$.

As far as I know it isn't a hard problem but I was stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $B=[b_1,\ldots,b_n]$ is the column partitioning of $B$, then the definition of the Frobenius norm and consistency of the matrix and vector 2-norms gives
$$
\|AB\|_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\|Ab_i\|_2^2\leq\|A\|_2^2\sum_{i=1}^n\|b_i\|_2^2=\|A\|_2^2\|B\|_F^2.
$$